# How to put the upcoming experience in Grad School Application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I am applying for Masters program in Computer Science and hoping to specialize in AI/ML. I will be the Teaching Assistant (T.A) for Machine Learning  class in the spring and most of the admissions deadlines are in the end of December. I think having this experience can make my application strong but how can I add this experience to the application as it will be in the coming future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is probably to get one of you letter writers to mention it "K.S. will TA for my course in ML this coming term." Something simple. This shows you are both trusted and respected.

You can mention it in a simple way in a SoP or a CV.

Don't overdo it. If you make it sound like your biggest accomplishment you will probably not benefit.

The normal decision process is based on other things. Make sure you focus on those.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Also is it ok to mention future experience on CV?

Comment: Actually, your acceptance as a TA is in the past. So, it isn't so different.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help!

Comment: You might want to put a "starting date" on your CV, just like one often puts "expected graduation date" on ongoing activities like being a PhD student.